# pthread not waiting for mutex lock threadFinished

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

Hi below is my coding snippet

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define TIMEOUT 3
int threadFinished = 0;
pthread_mutex_t g_mutex;

void *threadFunction(void* attr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
    char *pData = (char*)attr;
    if(pData)
    {
        printf("data from main thread is : %s\n",pData);
    }
    sleep(10);
    threadFinished = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);
    return (void*)"This is thread message !";
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    char *retVal = NULL;
    int iTimeOut = TIMEOUT;
    int i =0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&g_mutex,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,threadFunction,"Message from main thread");

    //printf("itimeout %d , threadrunning %d\n",iTimeOut,threadRunning);
    while(iTimeOut!=0 && !threadFinished)
    {
        printf("waiting %d\n",++i);
        sleep(1);
        iTimeOut--;
        printf("changing the threadfinish varible\n");
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex); //statement 1
        threadFinished = 1;
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex); // statement 2
        printf("changed the threadfinish varible\n");
    }

    if(iTimeOut==0)
    {
        if(!threadFinished)
        {
            printf("Timed out so cancelling the thread \n");
            pthread_cancel(tid);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("thread finished \n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("thread finished its job \n");
        pthread_join(tid,(void*)&retVal);

    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&g_mutex);
    threadFinished = 0;
    printf("message from thread is :  %s\n",retVal);
    return 0;
}
```

When statement1 & statement2 are commented I am expecting child thread to change my `testrunning` variable first before main thread but it is working properly only when statement1 and statement2 are uncommented.
My question is why in child thread mutex lock is not locking my `testrunning` variable . it is allowing main thread to modify `testrunning` variable.

Comment: Locks only lock themselves. You cannot lock a variable. What would that even mean?

Comment: @David . OMG ! simple and straight answer thanks .I understood now thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a variable concurrently from multiple threads, *each* thread needs to protect access to it via the same mutex. The `main()` thread fails to do so.

To correct this you could change `main()`'s while-loop like this:

```
  while (iTimeOut != 0)
  {
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
      int finished = threadFinished;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);

      if (finished)
      {
        break;
      }
    }

    printf("waiting %d\n",++i);

    sleep(1);
    iTimeOut--;

    printf("changing the threadfinish varible\n");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex); //statement 1
    threadFinished = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex); // statement 2

    printf("changed the threadfinish varible\n");
  }
```

Also you might like to consider narrowing locking to where it is necessary inside the thread-function like this:

```
void *threadFunction(void* attr)
{
  char *pData = attr; /* No need to cast here in C, as opposed to C++. */
  if(pData)
  {
    printf("data from main thread is : %s\n",pData);
  }
  sleep(10);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
  threadFinished = 1;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);

  return "This is thread message !"; /* No need to cast here in C, as opposed to C++. */
}
```

You should added error checking to all library calls in case a failure would influence the remaining execution.

Comment: Thanks 1. checking thread in while loop itself can cause any issue? 2. Why it is always recommended to use single mutex variable to lock & unloack in multiple threads ?

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya: Think twice: If you'd put the test for `threadFinished` inside the while-condition, where would you need to put the lock/unlock calls then? Would this make sense then?

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya: On the concept (the needs) of locking you might like to read for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29